# Is ssl for google app engine free?

Tags: security, google-app-engine, ssl

Do I have buy an SSL certificate to use https://myapp.appspot.com, or is it free of charge ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

No you don't have to bring your own certificate - appspot.com's SSL certificate is a wildcard SSL certificate that covers all the subdomains. In fact you can't bring your own certificate anyway.

Yes, the SSL certificate service provided by appspot.com is free, but check up on pricing models (by default, secure requests/traffic are counted same as normal bandwidth)

Pricing quotas for AppEngine:
http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas.html

See more information about using Secure URLs: 
http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/webxml.html#Secure_URLs

Comment: So can I use https in my appspot subdomain ?

Comment: @Horatiu - check the link I just posted. You have to set a security-constraint in your deployment descriptor.

Comment: I read about that. But it doesn't mention if it's free, that's why I asked

Comment: @Horatiu - appspot's SSL service is free, sorry I didn't mention that. HOWEVER, the price of using the service to do stuff might not be.

Comment: Thank you, hope they will allow https on own domains soon

Comment: It is now possible to use SSL on custom domains.

Answer (score 11):

It is possible to use SSL on custom domain on App Engine since 27 Jun 2012. Here is the documentation page: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/ssl

Answer (score 5):

As of September 2017 it is free.

Today Google AppEngine **Introducing managed SSL for Google App Engine** for customs domains. Please check following links for more information.

- https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2017/09/introducing-managed-SSL-for-Google-App-Engine.html
- https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/securing-custom-domains-with-ssl