# Google App Engine Data Protection

Tags: google-app-engine

I would like to know a few things about how google handles the data withing google app engine:

Where is the data located - is it possible to find out? 
How long will the data be stored? And what happens the data gets deleted?
Can you backup lost data or broken data?
What kind of security is added to protect the data?

Answer (score 0):

You can find most of the answers [here](https://developers.google.com/datastore/). More on [ACID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID)

- Where? Google data centers across the globe
- For how long? Forever is too much to say, so let's say for as long as you need the data to be there.
- If the data gets deleted?

  - If you delete it yourself it'll be propagated within a sensible timeframe infrastructurally speaking
  - If there are accidental errors on Google's side, the data is replicated and backed.
  - To protect against accidental errors on your side you can use [DataStore Admin](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/datastoreadmin) Console to back up your data
- Data is secured on Google's side. If you need to transfer sensitive information, App Engine enabled [SSL for custom domains](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/ssl) recently. If you don't want to go through the hassle of buying and registering certificates you can always use SSL through custom App Engine domain for free. More [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4370309/is-ssl-for-google-app-engine-free)

Comment: Thanks for ur reply! Is there anything wrong with this question - cause it has a negative rating?

Comment: Not sure, there are a pair of lexical typos, and maybe some didn't understand why you asked for how long is the data stored. To me your question looks ok enough :)

Comment: Ok...thank you very much...and sorry for the mistakes!