# Is my app secure with Google App Engine without my own SSL Certificate

Tags: google-app-engine, ssl

Is my app secure with Google App Engine without my own SSL Certificate?

I ask because I've just gone through the process of using Letsencrypt to create an SSL cert and apply it to my App Engine project with a custom domain - myapp.com

Now, I also a development environment which is at myapp.appspot.com. While configuring the app.yaml files with `secure: always`, I accidentally deployed the dev app before creating the certificates and I noticed it was secured!

I thought this could be an appspot.com thing, so I removed the certificates from my live app and it is still showing as secured...

So the question is, does App Engine have some sort of built-in SSL and thus, do I need to bother with my own certs???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your app at appspot.com is secure. However, if you wish to use a custom domain then you must get an SSL certificate. [Here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/console/using-custom-domains-and-ssl) you can find instructions on how to use a custom SSL certificate for a custom domain with appengine.

Comment: Can you explain why myapp.com is secure even though I've removed the SSL from the "custom domain" and also deleted the certificate?

Comment: Wait... it's NOT working now. Is there a delay after deletion?

Comment: I'm not sure why your custom domain was secure without an SSL certificate. As you mentioned, there's probably a delay. Here is some info about why the appspot.com domain is automatically secure: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4370309/is-ssl-for-google-app-engine-free